# Reason for USB power bank LED to be always on?

Tags: led, batteries, usb

I hope this is somewhat on topic.

I received a free 2200 mAh USB power bank today and noticed that inside its casing it has a blue LED that is always on, even when not giving charge or being charged.

[image: Blue light from within the power bank]

Are there any common design reasons for such behavior in a device of this kind? To me it just seemed peculiar for a device meant to retain energy.

(I don't have much experience in electronics)

Comment: Leakage current. Older simpler designs leak current through the boost inductor. Ten bucks says that the led is dim when not in use and brighter when in use?

Comment: @Passerby That is exactly right. It's the indicator led for discharging the device.

Comment: I like this question, let it live

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leakage current. Older simpler designs leak current through the boost inductor and diodes. Ten bucks says that the led is dim when not in use and brighter when in use? That's because it's tied directly to VUSB instead of a dedicated control IC like newer designs. Since the battery is not disconnected, it leaks and powers the led. When the current kicks up, the voltage of the boost circuit will rise to the 5V it is set for, and the led gets a higher voltage and hence brightness.

Basic Switching Circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbTsTR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switching circuit is off, the battery's 3.7V still leaks through L1 and D1. The battery typically has a protection circuit ([DW01 IC](http://homecircuits.eu/blog/arduino-low-voltage-disconnect-circuit/)) + mosfets that will disconnect it when the voltage hits the Over Voltage and Under Voltage thresholds, but in normal voltage ranges, are not affected. The battery is never disconnected.

It's not a minimum load for regulation, as that only matters when the current to a load is significant. While leaking it will be a milliamp or less.  It is actually discharging the battery unnecessarily, just very slowly. It's a bug in the design.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's the purpose of SW1? Wouldn't it just short the battery to ground?

Comment: @AndréBorie Very briefly, yes. This is a simple boost circuit, which uses an inductor to boost voltage from the available 3.7V to 5V for USB. The "switch" is electronically controlled, and automatically opened and closed at high speed.

Answer (score 3):

This LED is apparently connected to the charger output. This might be a "leakage", but also it might be the method how some (all?) chargers detect the presence of load. When phone gets charged and its power consumption goes below certain level (50-100mA), most chargers switche into some pulsed mode, to reduce waste (quiescent conversion current) when either the charge is done, or when nothing is connected. The duty cycle could be 1:100, or something. On every short ON cycle the LED goes full bright, so on average you see it glowing. When there is a load above threshold, the charger goes 100% on, charge begins, and the LED shines full scale.

Some chargers IC do have a dedicated status LED , which keeps it separate from output, so no light comes out after 15-20 seconds timeout. Apparently your charger is really on a cheap end, and has the LED simply on the output.

Comment: Both cheap and free :) I plugged in a 100% charged phone with a fresh battery, and the LED still shone bright. Does that qualify as leakage?

Comment: @Andreas, phones are tricky devices, they might need some time to determine if their internal battery does not need any charge. Or else. It is also possible that the constant "leakage" is also used to detect the load. So it is a "leakage" but with an intent.

Answer (score 1):

Some cheaper battery banks require a small current output all the time or at least once in a while for them to maintain a charge in the battery pack. That LED barely draws anything but it's not helping neither.